# This in classes and regular functions JS

Tags: this

When we have an object and a method inside it, this refers to the object that it belongs to:

```
let myObj = {
  data: 'someData',
  test() {
    console.log(this);
  },
};

myObj.test();
```

here the result is : myObj

but what if my method is in a class with constructor?

```
export default class MovieCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { content: 'test' };
  }

  changer() {
    console.log(this);
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

It seems, in this case, this equals to 'undefined'
why is that? is it because it has not been called yet?

Answer (score 0):

It is a special case when your class is a React.Component. The `this` keywords in methods (except the constructor) of such classes is not automatically bound to the instance of the component.

A common solution is to add the following line to the constructor (for each method using `this`):

```
constructor(props) {
    // ...
    this.changer = this.changer.bind(this);
}
```

It makes sure that your methods have correctly bound `this`'s.

For details of bind(): [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)